# mqtt.esm.js 1738:123 error

Tags: qt, java

I am getting an error ->

js: ./node_modules/mqtt/dist/mqtt.esm.js 1738:123
Module parse failed: Identifier directly after number (1738:123)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|     Xt(e, 'Missing "range" argument');
|     let i;

> ```
> return Number.isInteger(r) && Math.abs(r) > 2 ** 32 ? i = Yu(String(r)) : typeof r == "bigint" ? (i = String(r), (r > 2n ** 32n || r < -(2n ** 32n)) && (i = Yu(i)), i += "n") : i = Wi(r), "The value of \"".concat(t, "\" is out of range. It must be ").concat(e, ". Received ").concat(i);
> ```

|   }, RangeError);
|   _e("ERR_MULTIPLE_CALLBACK", "Callback called multiple times", Error);

I am using mosquitto mqtt , please help Me :(